# Retaining one duplicated row

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with duplicated rows in the columns cell line, pathway, drug  but the activity column has a different output. For example in the first two rows of the data frame below everything is the same from cell, drug to pathway except the activity, the first row has RESISTANT in the activity column and the second row has SENSITIVE in the activity column. I want to retain the second row, which has an output of SENSITIVE in the activity.

Could you please assist on how I can go about to  do that. I want to do this for all rows in the data frame that have an output like that, I want to retain the second duplicated row.

```
**cell**  **drug**         **pathway**   **activity**
AU656     5-FLORO          OTHER          RESISTANT
AU656     5-FLORO          OTHER          SENSITIVE
AU656     ALISERTIB        MITOSIS        INTERMEDIATE
AU656     ALISERTIB        MITOSIS        RESISTANT
AU656     AFITINIB         EGFR           SENSITIVE
AU656     AZD6482          PI3K           INTERMEDIATE
AU656     DORAMAPIMOD      JNK            INTERMEDIATE
AU656     DORAMAPIMOD      JNK            SENSITIVE
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, I do  not want to just focus on SENSITIVE. I was just making an example there. For all the groups that have the duplicates I want to select the second row, whether it is SENSITIVE, INTERMEDIATE or RESISTANT.

Comment: So you always want the second occurrence if a row is duplicated?

Comment: @kuhlemcinga if there is a single row, do you want to return that row for the group

Comment: Hi @Phil, yes that's what I want to do

Comment: @akrun if the is a single row I want to retain it. So if  a row is duplicated, I just want to keep the second occurrence

Comment: @kuhlemcinga in that case, check the solution I posted.  It does as what you requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by cell, drug, pathway and `slice` the 2nd row (if exists) by taking the `min`imum of 2 and group size (`n()`), thus for group sizes of 1, it returns the first row

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(cell, drug, pathway) %>%
   slice(min(2, n())) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  cell  drug        pathway activity    
  <chr> <chr>       <chr>   <chr>       
1 AU656 5-FLORO     OTHER   SENSITIVE   
2 AU656 AFITINIB    EGFR    SENSITIVE   
3 AU656 ALISERTIB   MITOSIS RESISTANT   
4 AU656 AZD6482     PI3K    INTERMEDIATE
5 AU656 DORAMAPIMOD JNK     SENSITIVE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(cell = c("AU656", "AU656", "AU656", "AU656", "AU656", 
"AU656", "AU656", "AU656"), drug = c("5-FLORO", "5-FLORO", "ALISERTIB", 
"ALISERTIB", "AFITINIB", "AZD6482", "DORAMAPIMOD", "DORAMAPIMOD"
), pathway = c("OTHER", "OTHER", "MITOSIS", "MITOSIS", "EGFR", 
"PI3K", "JNK", "JNK"), activity = c("RESISTANT", "SENSITIVE", 
"INTERMEDIATE", "RESISTANT", "SENSITIVE", "INTERMEDIATE", "INTERMEDIATE", 
"SENSITIVE")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```